# Initializing structure values in another structure

Tags: c, structure

I am trying to initialize values to a structure using another structure through this code:

```
struct freq
{
    char temp[20];
    int count=0;
};
struct test
{
    char input[100];
    struct freq words[20];
    int len;
}testdb[1] = 
{
    { "ram is playing.he likes playing", { { "ram", 1 }, { "is", 1 }, {"playing", 2 }, { "he", 1 }, { "like", 1 } }, 5 } 
};
```

but I get an error that cannot convert from `initializer` list to `freq`.
*What is the solution to this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the first struct.   I assume you are writing in C.   C doesn't have default values for struct members.

This compiles perfectly:

```
struct freq
{
    char temp[20];
    int count;
};
struct test
{
    char input[100];
    struct freq words[20];
    int len;
}testdb[1] = 
{
    { "ram is playing.he likes playing", { { "ram", 1 }, { "is", 1 }, {"playing", 2 }, { "he", 1 }, { "like", 1 } }, 5 } 
};
```